# How does HP Vugen locate the JRE used to record scripts?

Tags: java, settings, environment, loadrunner, vugen

Recording a Vugen script using Java over HTTP requires a JRE.

**How does HP Vugen locate this JRE used?**

On a Windows 7, I've installed a fresh copy of JRE (without JDK), removed the `PATH` system variable, deleted all the registry entries under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft`, and restarted HP Vugen. However, HP Vugen is still able to locate the installed JRE.

> I'm using HP Vugen 12.01.

Comment: I will ask the person responsible for this but my guess would be that it takes %LR_PATH%/jre

Comment: @Buzzy, Nice find =) though I'm not sure how am I going to verify that that's the version linked. More importantly, why is there a jre doing inside C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LoadRunner\ ?  If there's already a jre inside the installation, why doesn't Java recording work out-of-the-box?

Comment: This is not my area of the product, you can wait until the relevant guy answers my email or post the same question on the official LoadRunner support forum.

Comment: @Buzzy, The HP's support forum.... do people actually still use that? The formatting is terrible and it's full of black-white-only [WOTS](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=wall+of+text&rlz=1C1FDUM_enSG613SG613&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=4RaIVPOqIs7UuQS2hoCYBg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=675) slamming right into our eyeballs.

Comment: This forum: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF#.VIgh9CuUek4 It is pretty active and is viewed by our support staff and the R&D team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I got from the responsible engineer:

Record: Java over HTTP(JOH) protocol uses WEB protocol for recording and than convert C-script to Java-script. JOH recording doesn't depend on JRE at all.

Replay: For replay you **must** have installed JDK.

- Java 8 not supported yet
- "%LR_PATH%/jre" it is default JRE for **Flex** protocol.

LR uses JRE from JDK directory: JDK_PATH\jre.
You cannot change this setting from VuGen.
You can copy your own JRE to JDK_PATH\jre and use that JDK

Hope this helps

Comment: You stated JOH recording doesn't depend on JRE, but it says "JRE is not found. Version 1.5 or higher is required" http://i.stack.imgur.com/v5aFs.png when I tried to do exactly that. **Is this a bug?**

Comment: Additional debugging info: I've found that even when I have JDK and the JDK's JRE installed, The above error still exists. I must download the standalone JRE for the error to go away.